# Routing certain websites through a different local network interface in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a computer with two network interfaces (eth0 and usb0) and all traffic goes through eth0 but I want to use the other interface for certain requests (e.g. http://www.website.com) Is this possible?

Im guessing if at all possible it will have something to do with /etc/network/interfaces but haven't been able to figure it out

Comment: Are you talking about outgoing requests or incoming requests. In other words, are you running a webserver?

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a routing rule for each webserver you want to access with usb0. Find out the IP addresses of the webservers and add

```
ip route add <webserver ip> dev usb0
```

To make these routes permanent, you have to add them to the file

```
/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/route-usb0
```

But there is one problem left, what about changing IP addresses or webservers with multiple IPs?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about outgoing requests. You can split requests with iptables, etc on Linux but it is going to take some learning. An easier way is to use something like [Shorewall](http://www.shorewall.net/) to do it. Take a look at their [MultiISP](http://www.shorewall.net/MultiISP.html) document and in particular you are going to want to look at the "Routing Rules" section. You will need to set up rules for each interface.